# How to integrate $\int \frac{dx}{x\sqrt{x^4-1}}$?

Tags: calculus, integration

$$\int \dfrac{dx}{x\sqrt{x^4-1}}$$

I need to solve this integration.
I solved and got $\dfrac12\tan^{-1}(\sqrt{x^4-1}) + C$, however the answer given in my textbook is $\dfrac12\sec^{-1}(x^2) + C$

How can I prove that both quantities are equal? Is there something wrong with my answer?

**EDIT:**

Here's my work:
$$\int\dfrac{dx}{x\sqrt{x^4-1}}= \dfrac{1}{4}\int\dfrac{4x^3 dx}{x^4\sqrt{x^4-1}}$$

Let $x^4 - 1 = t^2$
$$\dfrac{1}{2}\int\dfrac{dx}{1 + t^2}$$

$$\dfrac12 \tan^{-1}(\sqrt{x^4 -1 }) + C$$

Comment: Post your solution as well please.

Comment: Hint: if $\tan y=\sqrt{x^4-1}$ then $\sec y=\pm\sqrt{1+\tan^2y}=\cdots$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is already solved with B. Goddard's answer, Here's an easy way to solve the given integral.

---

We have,
$$\int\dfrac{dx}{x\sqrt{x^4-1}}$$

Let $x^2 = \sec(\theta) \implies 2x \, dx = \sec(\theta) \tan(\theta) \, d\theta$

Which further implies that, $dx = \dfrac{\sqrt{\sec(\theta)}\tan(\theta)}{2}\, d\theta$

After substitution, the given integral changes to:
$$\dfrac12\int\dfrac{\sqrt{\sec(\theta)}\tan(\theta)}{\sqrt{\sec(\theta)}\cdot\sqrt{\sec^2(\theta) - 1}}\, d\theta$$

$$=\dfrac12\int\dfrac{\sqrt{\sec(\theta)}\tan(\theta)}{\sqrt{\sec(\theta)}\cdot\sqrt{\tan^2(\theta)}}\, d\theta$$

$$=\dfrac12\int\dfrac{\sqrt{\sec(\theta)}\tan(\theta)}{\sqrt{\sec(\theta)}\tan(\theta)}\, d\theta$$

$$=\dfrac12\int d\theta$$

$$=\dfrac12\theta + C$$

$$=\boxed{\dfrac12\sec^{-1}(x^2) + C}$$

Comment: Woah! Nice substitution.

Answer (score 2):

I tell my students that inverse trig functions are *angles.*  So if you write

$$\tan^{-1}\sqrt{x^4-1} = \theta,$$

then

$$\tan\theta = \sqrt{x^4-1}.$$

A right triangle that tells this story has $\theta$ as one angle, $\sqrt{x^4-1}$ as the opposite side and $1$ as the adjacent side.  Using Pythagorean theorem we can work out the length $c$ of the hypotenuse:

$$(\sqrt{x^4-1})^2+1^2 = c^2$$

which shows that $c=x^2$.

So $\sec \theta = x^2/1$, that is $\sec^{-1}(x^2) = \theta = \tan^{-1}( \sqrt{x^4-1}).$

Comment: It should be added that if $\tan^{-1} \sqrt{x^4-1} = \theta$ then $0 \le \theta < \pi/2$, since $\sqrt{x^4-1} \ge 0$.  That is needed to justify making a right triangle with angle $\theta$.

Answer (score 2):

The answer was already given by B. Goddard, here I try to give a visual answer:

[image]

Comment: Awesome, I didn't expect this. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your answer. The antiderivative you found is [correct](https://www.integral-calculator.com/#expr=%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bx%5Csqrt%7Bx%5E4-1%7D%7D).

Your book's answer is also [correct](https://www.integral-calculator.com/#expr=%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bx%5Csqrt%7Bx%5E4-1%7D%7D). The thing is that

$$\frac{1}{2}\tan^{-1}(\sqrt{x^4-1})=\frac{1}{2}\sec^{-1}(x^2)$$

If you don't believe me, see their [graphs](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/8hcmfzkbcv). The graphs of $\frac{1}{2}\tan^{-1}(\sqrt{x^4-1})$ and $\frac{1}{2}\sec^{-1}(x^2)$ are exactly the same.

**Edit:**

In order to prove that the quantities are indeed equal see [@Zaragosa's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4403111/768162).

---

**PS:** Whenever in doubt about calculus, use the [derivative-calculator](https://www.derivative-calculator.net/) or the [integral-calculator](https://www.integral-calculator.com/).